# Install PFX programmatically in Java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have generated some certificates using OpenSSL command line. Out of the batch of generated certificates I install PFX manually on server for enabling HTTPS call to my website. PFX was generated using following command -

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ca.crt -inkey ca.key -out ca.pfx
```

I install this on server by right click and "install certificate" (with no password).

I wish to do this through Java code. I tried using Java keytool -

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "C:\ca.pfx" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore clientcert.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

This prompts me for destination password and keystore password and without providing password it is not succeeding.

1) Is this the correct way of installing PFX on server. i.e. this will add the certificate to keyStore (java installed Jre location ) and not to **windows current user certificates** (mmc-> file -> add/remove snap in -> certificate -> my user account -> personal -> certificates).

2) Is there a better way of installing PFX using Java.

Comment: If you are using a Java application server like Tomcat/Wildfly, they can utilise PKCS12 key stores directly, without needing to convert into JKS.

Comment: Storing PKCS12 directly will be same as installing PFX to current user certificates?

Comment: It is unclear what your current setup is: which app server, are you using HTTPS with mutual authentication, and what you mean by "current user certificate". Are you setting up the client or the server side?

Comment: I am setting up server side, installing ca.pfx that is generated by ca.crt(Self signed root certificate). I follow usual window steps for installation and it reflects back in current user certificates(on server). In turn this certificate is available from browser for https calls for my application hosted on Apache.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... Where is the "programmatically" part? You have only shown commands. There should be some accompanying code.

Comment: Apologies for late response, but i am looking for an example to do it in java.

Comment: certutil –f -user –importpfx C:\ca.pfx - this command is installing certificate to current user. But doing this with Java native code would be a preffered solution